# Counting Survey Answers of users ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, session

I'm building an online application for a survey. I want to count how many users answers a specific question. My question is, how would I count the answer using Session state and application state? The answers are inputs of radio boxes and check box lists.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Save the user replies in your database as normal, then come back later and query your database to answer questions like that.